# How to create a login screen using core python language

Tags: python, web-services, authentication

I need to develop a simple login page using Python language with two fields and a button, like:

```
Username, Password, Login
```

I know there are some beautiful Python frameworks like

```
Django, Grok, WebPy, TurboGears
```

which support web development using Python, but mine is a basic requirement consisting of only 3 screens (pages):

- 1st page  -  Login page (Redirects to 2nd page when login button is clicked)
- 2nd page  -  Page with records in the form of a list, with an option for adding new records (Redirects to 3rd page when "Add Records" button is clicked)
- 3rd page  -  Page with fields, which are saved as records for the list on 2nd page  (After entering details and clicking Submit)

So, I have decided to develop the above functionality using Python **without** using any framework, so that I can have flexibility as well as write my own code.

1. Is it possible to create a login page using Python without using a framework?
2. I haven't worked on web services and don't know the basics of web development in Python.
3. If possible, can you provide me an example on how to create a login page using Python and achieve the functionality described above?

Comment: It's possible, but I wouldn't recommend it. It'll probably be faster to learn a micro web framework (I recommend [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)) than to implement all of this with CGI. If you want to try to do it, there's the [`cgi`](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html) module.

Comment: @Blender: Thanks very much for ur suggestion, can u provide me an example so that i can look in to it fastly rather than learning the cgi concept and trying to develop with it.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it's good to learn how to do things without the frameworks, but if you're doing this for anything but educational purposes it's most likely a mistake to say "my requirements are too simple to bother with frameworks." What you describe is on the simpler end of the spectrum, but already I can see some complications you're probably glossing over.

Anyway, to implement your 3 pages, you will need:

- a web server
- 2 static HTML files
- python handlers for GET on 2nd Page, POST from 1st and 3rd Page
- storage (either flat file or database)

Look at [A Simple Python CGI Server Tutorial](http://pointlessprogramming.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/python-cgi-tutorial-1/) to get started, and there are more details at [TutorialsPoint: Python - CGI Programming](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm).

Your HTML forms just need to have `method="POST"` and `action` set to the URL you're serving from python for each form. Your POST handlers should do what they need to do and then serve a 302 redirect.

If you don't know the basics of python web development, you're going to have your hands full and should probably start with a single user flat-file system. Maybe you can even get away with storing that in memory for now. Then if/when that stops doing it for you, try sqlite. Configuring web servers is a pain, too, so if you can just stick with `BaseHTTPServer`.

Finally, load your records in another python endpoint, make some HTML for each, slap it in a big string with surrounding HTML, and serve that puppy.

Answer (score 0):

You requirement is very trivial. Though people may suggest micro frameworks like flask, bottle I would say you should try Django and have a look at Django Admin Panel. I think it's possible for you to meet your requirement using the Django admin feature.

**Updated**

Have a look at this http://docs.python.org/howto/webservers.html

Without a framework and if you don't want to mess with CGI you can take a look at http://webob.org/ .

Comment: The question says: "through python with out using any framework". So Django seems not to be an option.

Comment: yup, i will agree with you this is a basic requirement.But this requirement is temporary so for this we don't want to use the standard framework(django) or some others for a small use. Is there a way to implement login screen python without using frameworks

Comment: my bad I probably read the question too fast and skipped the no framework part.

Comment: Bleh on recommending Django, but +1 for the sentiment that it probably would be quicker/better/easier using a framework after all.